# Scale colormap for contour and contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the contour map of a given function f(x,y), but since the functions output scales really fast, I'm losing a lot of information for lower values of x and y. I found on the forums to work that out using `vmax=vmax`, it actually worked, but only when plotted for a specific limit of x and y and levels of the colormap.

Say I have this plot:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
u = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
x,y = np.meshgrid(u,u)
z =  (1-x)**2+100*(y-x**2)**2
cont = plt.contour(x,y,z,500,colors='black',linewidths=.3)
cont = plt.contourf(x,y,z,500,cmap="jet",vmax=100)
plt.colorbar(cont)
plt.show
```

I want to uncover whats beyond the axis limits keeping the same scale, but if I change de x and y limits to -3 and 3 I get:

[image]

See how I lost most of my levels since my max value for the function at these limits are much higher. A work around to this problem is to increase the levels to 1000, but that takes a lot of computational time.

Is there a way to plot only the contour levels that I need? That is, between 0 and 100.

An example of a desired output would be:

[image]

With the white space being the continuation of the plot without resizing the levels.

The code I'm using is the one given after the first image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible ideas here. The one I very much prefer is a logarithmic representation of the data. An example would be

```
from matplotlib import ticker
fig = plt.figure(1)
cont1 = plt.contourf(x,y,z,cmap="jet",locator=ticker.LogLocator(numticks=10))
plt.colorbar(cont1)
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure(2)
cont2 = plt.contourf(x,y,np.log10(z),100,cmap="jet")
plt.colorbar(cont2)
plt.show()
```

The first example uses matplotlibs LogLocator functions. The second one just directly computes the logarithm of the data and plots that normally.

The third example just caps all data above 100.

```
fig = plt.figure(3)
zcapped = z.copy()
zcapped[zcapped>100]=100
cont3 = plt.contourf(x,y,zcapped,100,cmap="jet")
cbar = plt.colorbar(cont3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The third example is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks!